# Lists of lists losing data after pointer arithmetics

Tags: c++, list, pointers

I been programming a set of lists holing pointer to lists, and wanna create an convenient interface to brows them and save selected data from file to lists. The idea is that there is one "API list" with unique id, and whenever I find an unique id, I shall create a new API list. For now I'm stack on saving data to one "API list's" related lists.

The structure looks simply like this:

```
enum day { mon, tue, wed, thu, fri, sat, sun };
static const string enumValues[] = { "mon", "tue", "wed", "thu", "fri", "sat", "sun" };

struct _ListSub {
  string h;
  day d;
  string gr;
  string sub;
  _ListSub *next = nullptr;
};

struct ListAPI {
  string id;
  ListAPI *next = nullptr;
  _ListSub *head = nullptr;
};
```

And my function to read and save values from the file to the lists look like this:

```
ListAPI *createLists(string arg) {
  ifstream f_in;
  ListAPI *listGrip;

  f_in.open(arg);

  if (!f_in.is_open()) {
    cout << "\"" << arg << "\": file does not exist!" << endl;
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  listGrip = new ListAPI;
  listGrip->head = new _ListSub;

  while (true) {
    // dummy data
    string h;
    string week = "";
    string gr;
    string id;
    string sub;

    if (!(f_in >> h >> week >> gr >> id >> sub)) {
      break;
    }

    cout << "ID check: " << checkListID(id, listGrip) << endl;

    listGrip->id = id;
    listGrip->head->h = h;
    listGrip->head->d = (day)enumerateDay(week);
    listGrip->head->gr = gr;
    listGrip->head->sub = sub;

    listGrip->head ++;
    listGrip->head = new _ListSub;
  }

  f_in.close();

  return listGrip;
}
```

Any ways, the data is correct, it worked fine, so long didn't add this part (moving head pointer of `_listSub` and creating new instance of this object):

```
listGrip->head ++;
listGrip->head = new _ListSub;
```

All data that I'm getting out of this is id witch I save to `listGrip` (my list API), however all the data from the nested list list is gone.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here with pointers?

MAIN:

```
int main( int argc, char **argv ) {

  /* Directly parse options in order to avoid accepting abbrevations. */
  string ARGUMENT;
  validate_arguments;

  cout << "File path: " << ARGUMENT << endl;
  ListAPI *listGrip;

  listGrip = createLists( ARGUMENT );

  //listGrip->head;

  cout << "List has been created." << endl;
  cout << "ID: " << listGrip->id << endl;
  cout << "Subject: " << listGrip->head->sub << endl;
  cout << "Time: " << listGrip->head->h << endl;
  cout << "Day: " << getTextFromEnum((short)listGrip->head->d) << endl;

  delete listGrip;
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Where is `main()`? Please post a [mcve]. Don't describe your code but show it.

Comment: "Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here with pointers?" Everything. You can only do pointer arithmetic with pointers that point into an array, which `head` doesn't. Moreover, `head = new ...` discards the old `head` which you have worked so hard to build.

Comment: I recommend you draw a linked list with 3 elements on a piece of paper, then place a marker on the head pointer and simulate adding a new elemet by moving the marker and drawing a new node as appropriate.

Comment: _ListSub identifier is reserved. Pick another name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linked-List is an abstract structure connecting loosely placed nodes. As nodes are not placed next to each other we can not preform pointer arithmetics to get to the next node. In stead we can create an insert function witch is going to redirect pointers for us.

#### Redirecting nodes:

Classical Linked-List contain the `next` pointer in it's structure, pointing to the next node of the same type. For convince we can add `prev`ious  pointer and a size variable to keep track of list size.

```
void insertSub(string h, day d, string gr, string sub) {
  auto newNode = new _ListSub;

  //initialize
  newNode->h = h;
  newNode->d = d;
  newNode->gr = gr;
  newNode->sub = sub;

  // point new node to the currently previous and next node
  newNode->next = node->next;
  newNode->prev = node;

  // point currently next and previous node to the new node
  node->next->prev = newNode;
  node->next = newNode;

  // increment size
  ++ node->size;
}
```

This works for my structure, but probably you wanna use constructor for object initialization.

Answer (score 1):

```
listGrip->head ++;
```

Makes no sense. head points to a single _ListSub. When you increment it, it will point to some random memory after the _ListSub you've allocated. This random memory is not yours and could lead to memory corruption or if you are lucky to a SegFault.

What you probably want is to insert at head:

```
auto new_head = new _ListSub;
new_head->next = listGrip->head;
listGrip->head = new_head;
```

Or even better use the Standard library. There's a `std::list` in there already, it's well tested and it works.

Comment: Thanks, that comment helped me at the moment. I was pretty and it wasn't my program so I couldn't really grasp the concept. Any ways I think this structure is stupid itself. Finally I make an head structure (`node`) pointing to it self with `next` and `prev` pointer and an insert function. Simple enough.